# SendInput fail because of UIPI

Tags: c#, certificate, sendinput, uipi

I am try to simulate mouse event on Win7, and my application using an open source project "Windows Input Simulator" on website http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ which internally use codes below to simulate mouse event:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);
```

My application runs perfectly when I debug it with Visual Studio 2010. The left button click event, right button click event and mouse move event are ok. But the click events not send when I start my application from Explorer by double click the .exe application excutable file. Only the mouse move event is OK, if I try to simulate left button click or right click, my application will receive an exception and exit.
I have found the exception is throw by codes below:

```
public void DispatchInput(INPUT[] inputs)
{
    if (inputs == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inputs");
    if (inputs.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("The input array was empty", "inputs");
    var successful = NativeMethods.SendInput((UInt32)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (INPUT)));
    if (successful != inputs.Length)
            throw new Exception("Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.");
}
```

That says UIPI blocked the SendInput(...). So I Google this topic, and get some advises.

1) Add uiAccess="true" to my application's manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

2) Create a test certificate and add this certificate to local machine Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store and the Trusted Publishers certificate store.

```
MakeCert -r -pe -ss PrivateCertStore -n "CN=Test Certificate - For Internal Use Only" testcert.cer
CertMgr.exe /add testcert.cer /s /r localMachine root
CertMgr.exe /add testcert.cer /s /r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

3) Sign my application with previous digital signature

```
SignTool sign /v /s PrivateCertStore /n "Test Certificate - For Internal Use Only" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll MyApplication.exe
```

4) Install my application to "C:\Program Files" folder which is one of the secure locations on my computer.

I think I have done all things to satisfy UIPI requirements, but the problem still not solve after I start my application and agree the UAC prompt. Only mouse move event is ok.

PS: if I don't sign my application with test certificate and only add "requestedExecutionLevel" with uiAccess="true" in manifest, application will not start and Windows show a dialog with message "A referral was returned from the server.". If I signed my application with test certificate, UAC will work when I start my application. The application will work until I call SendInput to simulate click event and then exception threw.

I have read the requirements about "Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) and integrity" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx, but after doing all this, still not work.

I have found a blog, In this blog, it says

> By specifying UIAccess=”true” in the requestedPrivileges attribute [of the application manifest], the application is stating a requirement to bypass UIPI restrictions on sending window messages across privilege levels. Windows Vista implements the following policy checks before starting an application with UIAccess privilege.
>   The application must have a digital signature that can be verified using a digital certificate that chains up to a trusted root in the local machine Trusted Root
>   Certification Authorities certificate store.
>   The application must be installed in a local folder application directory that is writeable only by administrators, such as the Program Files directory.
>
> Unfortunately this is not going to work if you application can be
>   installed by non-admin users.

I want to know how to make my application not conform to the last sentence "Unfortunately this is not going to work if you application can be installed by non-admin users" and can bypass UIPI by add uiAccess="true" in manifest.

Any one can help me about this?

Comment: Hi Chen. I am facing same issue. have you found any solution?